# Jekyll not creating the post directory in _site folder

Tags: html, ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

May be my question is close to [this question][1]. However, the solution proposed there didn't work for me. Hence, creating a new question here.

My `config.yml` looks as follows:

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site settings
title: Some title ..
author1: Alice
author2: Bob
author_link1: https://www.facebook.com/alice
author_link2: https://www.facebook.com/bob
author_description: Alice and Bob's cool site
email: your-email@domain.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Some lines and dots in the end.......
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://example.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

# Picturefill
# A responsive image polyfill: http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/
picturefill: false

# Typography
# To use, publish a kit and enter the ID here. If you do not wish to use Typekit,
# leave this ID blank
typekit_kit_id: 

# Build settings
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty

# Pagination
paginate: 5

# Sass
sass:
    style: :compressed

#This is to include future posts. Without this if a post is of future date, Jekyll will fail
future: true
```

The output of `jekyll build --verbose` is as follows:

```
Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /home/alice/Downloads/website/_config.yml
       Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.
         Requiring: jekyll-paginate
         Requiring: kramdown
            Source: /home/alice/Downloads/awesome-site
       Destination: /home/alice/Downloads/awesome-site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile.lock
       EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile
           Reading: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
        Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 0.00028435 seconds.
         Rendering: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
         Requiring: kramdown
  Rendering Layout: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
         Rendering: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown
         Rendering: feed.xml
  Pre-Render Hooks: feed.xml
  Rendering Liquid: feed.xml
  Rendering Markup: feed.xml
  Rendering Layout: feed.xml
         Rendering: index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: index.html
  Rendering Liquid: index.html
  Rendering Markup: index.html
  Rendering Layout: index.html
         Rendering: css/screen.scss
  Pre-Render Hooks: css/screen.scss
  Rendering Liquid: css/screen.scss
  Rendering Markup: css/screen.scss
                    done in 0.088 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

The only post `2018-04-09-awesome.markdown` contains the following content

```
---
layout: page
title:  "Our page"
date: 2018-04-09 
categories: 
location: 
---

Some content
```

Also, the `_includes/post.html` file has a commented line which has got something to do with the dates. But, I hope that is not causing the problem.

```
<article class="post">
    <header>
        <a href="{{ include.post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
            <h1 class="post-title">{{ include.post.title }}</h1>
        </a>
        <!-- <time datetime="{{ include.post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" class="post-date">{{ include.post.date | date: "%A, %B %-d, %Y" }}</time> -->
        <time class="post-date"> Alice and Bob's cool website </time>
    </header>
    <div class="post-body">
        {% if include.post.location %}<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/{{ include.post.location }}" target="_blank" class="post-body-location">{{ include.post.location }}</a><span class="post-body-location-divider">—</span>{% endif %}{{ include.content }}
    </div>
    <footer class="post-footer">
        {% if include.post.location %}<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/{{ include.post.location }}" target="_blank" class="post-footer-location">{{ include.post.location }}</a>{% endif %}
    </footer>
</article>
```

Where am I doing wrong? How to solve this? I am trying to host it on Github, and the build is failing. I believe, not having _post folder is one of the reasons for build fail.

While the parent folder has following folders and files,

```
CNAME  _config.yml  css  feed.xml  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  img  _includes  index.html  js  _layouts  LICENSE  _posts  README.md  _sass  _site
```

The _site folder only has the following content.

```
2018  CNAME  css  feed.xml  img  index.html  js  LICENSE  README.md
```

I believe, something is wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is normal here.

Jekyll is generating posts with `permalink: pretty` set as configuration ([see documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#builtinpermalinkstyles)).

That means that a post at **_posts/2018-04-09-awesome.markdown** will have an url following `/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/` pattern, and will be generated in **2018/04/09/awesome/index.html**.

Comment: Update the question based on your answer. The look and feel between local and live version is different. Especially the markdown css seems to be not picking up the css properties as it is.

Comment: This is another problem. You can approve my answer and ask a new question on SO.

Comment: Sure, here is the new question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/48994637/2888239