# Fonts and other styles are different in local and gihub pages live version of Jekyll

Tags: html, css, fonts, github-pages, webfonts

I see changes in the look and feel of local and live version (hosted on Github).

**Below is the local version..**
[image: Here is the local version]

**and here is the live version**
[image: Here is the live version]

**The font-style, etc. seems to be different in these versions?**

Below are my css codes.

```
# _sass/_layout.scss

#banner {
    /* @include retina-background-image($img-banner); */
    /* background-color: #8e8387;*/
    outline: none;
    // display: block;
    // width: $banner-width;
    // height: $banner-height;
    margin: 35px 0 auto 35px;
    position: relative; 
    /* To ensure the bottom border is positioned correctly */

    h1 {
        // Font is included from Google Fonts automatically unless a custom banner is used
        // See _config.yml for details
        font-family: $banner-font-family;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        color: #fefefe;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &::after {
        // display: block;
        // position: absolute;
        // top: $banner-height;
        // left: $banner-border-offset;
        // content: "";
        // background: #443E40;
        // height: $banner-border-width;
         width: $banner-width - ($banner-border-offset* 2);
    }

    @include min-breakpoint($image-splitting-breakpoint) {
        // margin-bottom: $banner-margin;
    }
}

#footer {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    /* &::after {
        @include retina-background-image($img-dude);
        display: block;
        content: "";
        width: 65px;
        height: 158px;
        margin: 20px auto 50px;
    } */

    a {
        // Overwrite default link color
        color: #222;

        &:hover {
            // ... but allow the hover color to work as normal
            color: $hover-color;
        }
    }

    p {
        margin: 0 0 9px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        font-size: 19px;
        max-width: 75%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

        @include min-breakpoint($image-splitting-breakpoint) {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1;
        }
    }
}

section[role="main"] {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    @include min-breakpoint($desktop-breakpoint) {
        width: $layout-width;
    }
}
```

And then,

```
# css/screen.scss

---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
@charset "utf-8";

// Typography
$base-font-family: "adobe-caslon-pro", "Adobe Caslon Pro", serif;
$caption-font-family: "ltc-bodoni-175", "Libre Baskerville", serif;
$banner-font-family: "Sanchez", serif;
$title-font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
$base-font-size:   18px;
$base-font-weight: 400;
$base-line-height: 1;

// Colours
$text-color:       #222;
$caption-text-color: #444;
$border-color: #979797;
$background-color: #fefefe;
$content-width:    750px;
$hover-color: #443E40;
$legal-color: #818181;

// Layout
$layout-width: 750px;

// Breakpoints
$desktop-breakpoint: $layout-width / 0.9;
$image-splitting-breakpoint: 510px;

// Banner
 $banner-width: 182px;
 $banner-height: 503px;
 $banner-margin: 50px;
 $banner-border-width: 3px;
 $banner-border-offset: 2px;

// Images
// Note that extensions are omitted for use in retina-background-image mixin

$img-separator: '{{ site.baseurl }}/img/separator';
$img-banner: '{{ site.baseurl }}/img/banner';
$img-dude: '{{ site.baseurl }}/img/dude';
$img-location: '{{ site.baseurl }}/img/icon-location';

// Import partials from `sass_dir` (defaults to `_sass`)
@import
        "mixins",
        "vendors",
        "base",
        "layout",
        "modules"
;
```

And the html code is below

```
---
layout: page
title: "Our journey"
date: 2018-04-09 
categories: 
location: 
---

Alice and Bob are about to start a wonderful journey with their cat.

We will start their journey on
<div style="text-align:center;">
<p class="post-image-caption"><strong>9th April, 2018</strong> <br/><span style="font-size: 90%;">9.00 AM onwards.<br/>(To be specific: 9.30 AM)</span></p>
</div>

<div class="post-image post-image--split">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/365x270/8e8387/ffffff" alt="The first in an example of split-imagery" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/365x270/8e8387/ffffff" alt="The second in an example of split-imagery" />
</div> 

<p class="post-image-caption"><strong>This is their cat</strong><span style="font-size: 85%;"> (<a style ="color:blue;" href="../img/catpic.png" target="_blank">Her pic</a>)</span> <br>She purrs, <br>She is very cute and calm<br> </p>

<div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x563/8e8387/ffffff" alt="A full-size image example" />
    <p class="post-image-caption">Here we demonstrate a caption. This'll adapt to any length of text.</p>
</div>
```

Seems like css itself has other problems as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992156/why-is-the-site-focus-is-in-the-middle-of-the-page-rather-than-the-beginning) - where on page load it focuses to the middle of the page rather than the beginning of the page. Most likely, this is not related to the different views of the fonts. However, I thought of linking it here for reference.

Comment: If I had to guess, you're using a webfont, and a problem with the URL is causing it to only load in one place but not the other. But you haven't posted any code, so I have no way to say for sure.

Comment: You mean the css code?

Comment: I mean literally any code at all lol. The CSS and the rest of the web page code. I can't debug code that I can't see.

Comment: Lol! I thought I did. Now I have updated css as well as the html code.

Comment: This comment catches my eye: "Font is included from Google Fonts automatically unless a custom banner is used". I'm guessing something's going on where the Google Fonts aren't getting included when they should be. You'll have to poke around in the server's outputted HTML to debug further.

Comment: Any tips on how to poke around server's outputted HTML to degub it further?

```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:700|Sanchez" type="text/css">``` is the only line of web-font used in some layout file.

Comment: Just use the 'view source' option in your web browser (https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm). That line of code is important -- make sure it appears the same on both versions of the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165857/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-hayden-schiff).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165858/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-hayden-schiff).

Comment: If you don't want things to look different, don't use font families that "can be more than one font", use explicit `@font-face` rules to specify *exactly* which font families should be available to CSS, and then *exclusively* use those. So no `"adobe-caslon-pro", "Adobe Caslon Pro", serif`. Load that Caslon family with a `@font-face` rule (probably through typekit or some other legal means, because Caslon is _very not free at all_) and then use `font-family: Caslon` in your CSS.